# How to make a loop that validates the user-input dates based on the functions created?

Tags: python, loops

I am not using any datetime module. I created my own functions to calculate the day, month, and year. I want to calculate the refunds based on the date. If the date is invalid, it should ask the user to try again until a date is true.

```
year = 0
month = 0
day = 0
money_owed = 0

def if_leap_year(year):

    if (year % 400 == 0): return 366
    
    elif (year % 100 == 0): return 365
    
    elif (year % 4 == 0): return 366

    else:
        return 365

#print(if_leap_year(year))

def days_in_month(month, year):
    if month in {1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12}:
        return 31
    if month == 2:
        if if_leap_year(year):
            return 29
        return 28
    return 30

#print(days_in_month(month, year))

def is_valid_date(year, month, day):
  if days_in_month(month, year)<day:#checks if the given day is possible 
given the month
    return False
  else:
    return True



def days_left_in_year(month, day, year):
    daysInMonth = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
    daysLeft = (if_leap_year(year) if month < 3 else 365) - 
sum(daysInMonth[:month - 1]) - day
    return daysLeft

def refund_period():
        month = int(input("Enter the month of the year: "))
        day = int(input("Enter the day of the year: "))
        year = int(input("Enter the year to determine the number of days: "))      
        if is_valid_date(year , month , day):
            money_owed = (days_left_in_year(month, day, year) / 
if_leap_year(year)) * 278
            return round(money_owed, 2)
        else:
            print("Your date is invalid, try again.")


while is_valid_date(year, month, day):
    print('you will be refunded','$', + refund_period())
    break
else:
    print("Your date is invalid, try again.")
```

I am getting:

```
you will be refunded $ -8.38
```

even though the calculation shouldn't be performed since the date is invalid

Comment: What are you trying to make?

Comment: `if_leap_year` returns a _number_ like 365 or 366. What do you mean by code like `if if_leap_year(year):`? This will be interpreted as `if bool(if_leap_year(year)) is True:`, but since `if_leap_year(year) > 0`, this will _always_ be `True`. Also the name `if_leap_year` doesn't reflect what the function actually does. It should be `number_of_days_in_year` to prevent any confusion.

Comment: I want for the `def refund_period():` function to run based on the user inputs of the day, month, and year. The while loop I am trying to make is so that the inputs entered are validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `year =0 , month =0, day = 0` in first loop.
Also the  `while` is not clear. All your functions return an int so never validate if the date is correct.
Maybe you can create a function to validate the date something like this :

```
def is_valid_date(year , month , day):
    if month <1 or month >12: #Validate a allowed month
        return False
    if day <1 or day > days_in_month(month, year): # validate an allowed day for the month
        return False
    return True
```

and you can change this function :

```py
    def refund_period():
        month = int(input("Enter the month of the year: "))
        day = int(input("Enter the day of the year: "))
        year = int(input("Enter the year to determine the number of days: "))      
        if is_valid_date(year , month , day):
            money_owed = (days_left_in_year(month, day, year) / if_leap_year(year)) * 278
            return round(money_owed, 2)
        else :
            print("Your date is invalid, try again.")
```

Just a couple of comments:

- You are getting the year, month, and day using `input()` so you don't need to create global variables for that.
- you don't need to ask if `if_leap_year(year) == 365 or 366` because this function returns 365 or 366 so you can use it directly when you calculate the money_owned, as I do.
- Also you can use  `if_leap_year(year)`  instead
  `(if_leap_year(year) if month < 3 else 365)`  . That functions return 366 or 365, you dont need to validate again.
- And  you can use list comprehension for you `daysInMonth` variable inside `days_left_in_year` function  :
  `daysInMonth = [days_in_month(m, year) for m in range(1,13)]`

Comment: I am getting `you will be refunded $ -9.11` despite the fact that I defined the validation.

Comment: just curiosity, which values for day, month, and year are you using?

Comment: 13 for the month, 12 for the day, and 2020 for the year.

Comment: Your  `is_valid_date` function doesn't work because you never validate the month. I updated my answer changing the is_valid_date

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop is not comparing the function value but just checking if the object exists. Instead of conditions like `while days_left_in_year(month, day, year)`, use conditions like `while days_left_in_year(month, day, year)<30` (assuming you wanted to deny refunds on orders older than 30 days.

To validate dates, add the following function under your comment `#print(days_in_month(month, year))`:

```py
def is_valid_date(year, month, day)
  if days_in_month(month, year)<day:#checks if the given day is possible given the month
    return False
  else:
    return True
```

then your condition should look something like this:

```py
if ((is_valid_date(year, month, day) == True) and (month<13)):
    print('you will be refunded','$', + refund_period())
else:
    print("Your date is invalid, try again.")
```

Comment: It is not really to deny refunds for older than 30 days, but deny the refund if the date entered is invalid.

Comment: what do you mean by invalid? as in not the current year? What if a user orders something on Dec. 31 2022 and wants a refund on Jan 1 2023?

Comment: Say for example, if a user tries to enter 13 for the month, 29, for the date, and 2021 for the year the program would ask the user to try again since that date does not exist.

Comment: I would create an additional function to validate and add it as a param, I will update my answer.

Comment: The calculation is still being performed despite the month being incorrect. I get `$-`, with the calculation instead of the `else` statement being shown.

Comment: @beginner_geek07 I forgot to add something to filter months, I'll add it now.